# Is it possible to make event.preventDefault() happen by default?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I'm working on a project where pretty much every `a` element is connected to JavaScript via the `onclick` handler, using just a blank `href` value.  I don't want to follow the href at all, so I've been using `event.preventDefault()`. There are two main ways I've used:

- With `preventDefault()` happening in onclick:
  HTML:  `onclick="event.preventDefault();onclickHandler();"`
       JS:  `function onclickHandler() { ...`
- With `preventDefault()` happening in the JavaScript function:
  HTML:  `onclick="onclickHandler(event)"`
       JS:  `function onclickHandler(event) { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Neither of these seems ideal to me.  With the first, I have to remember to place the call to `preventDefault()` in *every* onclick handler, with risk of missing one.  With the second, there's an extra parameter going into the function that doesn't significantly add to the function's, well, function.

What I'm trying to do is configure that `a` tag to use `preventDefault()` without my having to explicitly tell it to do so.  **Can it be done?**

Answer (score 0):

Remove `href` option from `a` tag, so it won't act as a hyperlink.
If you want pointer to change on hover then use CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid modifying the cursor if possible.

Comment: So you don't want to use Javascript nor CSS? Then, you can't do that.